# Firebase Google Analytics using node.js

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-contacts-api

I am trying to pull the google analytics, which are linked to my firebase account. I am using "googleapi" npm module for that. My purpose is to get the analytics such as "user sessions", "engagement rate", "users" etc in my admin dashboard, which is built in React.

I am trying to get the view id from my analytics account admin view. But for that particular project,, it does not show the view block, like it shows for other. I have attached screenshot of both the screens, in one it shows the view property and other it does not. I would like to show it for both. Can anyone help how can i show it for both ? Is some setting change required ? [image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Your second property is a Google Analytics 4 property. Google Analytics 4 properties do not have views. The "googleapi" npm module you are using probably only supports Universal Analytics.

Comment: can you please help, how can I get analytics from that property ? Any npm module or reference that can guide ? I did a lot of search but hasn't found anything helpful yet.

Comment: I get data for other properties,, but this particular one i get this error "Error: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.". Solutions over internet says to  add permissions by going into the view. But there is not option to change as per the suggestions under this view. Though the account I am using has full set of permissions.